# Flex and Bison does not seem to match

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to build a simple calculator, as in you type an arithmetic expression and press Enter to have your expression parsed and result calculated.

The following code works (just bison) which a friend gave to me:

```
%{                
   #include<stdio.h>                                                                   
   #include <math.h>                                                       
   #define YYSTYPE double

   extern int line_number;                                                            
   int line_number=0;                                                                     
void yyerror(char *err)
{
   printf("Error: %s\n", err);
}
%}                                                                                   

%token NUMBER        /* define token type for numbers */
%token PLUS
%token MINUS
%token MULT
%token DIV
%token NEWLINE
%token LPAR
%token RPAR

%%     /* Bison grammar rules */
input   : /* empty production to allow an empty input */
        | line input  
        ;
line    : expr NEWLINE   { printf("Result is %f\n", $1); }
expr    : expr PLUS term   { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        | expr MINUS term   { $$ = $1 - $3; }
        | term            { $$ = $1; }
        ;
term    : term MULT factor { $$ = $1 * $3; }
        | term DIV factor { $$ = $1 / $3; }
        | factor          { $$ = $1; }
        ;
factor  : LPAR expr RPAR    { $$ = $2; }
        | NUMBER          { $$ = $1; }
        ;
;                                                                                    
%%                                                                                   

int yylex( void ) {
    int c = getchar();      /* read from stdin */
    if (c < 0) return 0;        /* end of the input*/
    while ( c == ' ' || c == '\t' ) c = getchar( );
    if ( isdigit(c) || c == '.' ) {
    ungetc(c, stdin);    /* put c back into input */
    scanf_s ("%lf", &yylval); /* get value using scanf */
    return NUMBER;       /* return the token type */
    }
    if(c=='+')
        return PLUS;
    if(c=='-')
        return MINUS;
    if(c=='*')
        return MULT;
    if(c=='/')
        return DIV;
    if(c=='\n')
        return NEWLINE;
    if(c=='(')
        return LPAR;
    if(c==')')
        return RPAR;
    return c; /* anything else... return char itself */
}

main ()                                                                              
{
  yyparse ();
}
```

Now when I try to split it into two files it just calls the main function and does seems to accept input but nothing is shown on the screen:

calc.l:

```
%{
#include "calc.tab.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define YYSTYPE double
%}
%option noyywrap
%option never-interactive

NUM  [0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
white [ \r\t]+ 

%%
{white} { }
{NUM}  {yylval=atof(yytext);return NUM;}
"+"    {return PLUS;}
"-"    {return MINUS;}
"/"    {return DIV;}
"*"    {return MUL;}
"("    {return LP;}
")"    {return RP;}
"\n"   {return NL;}
%%
```

calc.y :

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define YYSTYPE double

%}

%token NUM
%token PLUS
%token MINUS
%token MUL
%token DIV
%token LP
%token RP
%token NL

%%

Input   :
    | Line Input
    ;

Line    : Exp NL        { printf("Result = %f\n", $1); }


Exp : Exp PLUS Term     { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | Exp MINUS Term    { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    | Term          { $$ = $1; }
    ;

Term    : Term MUL Fact     { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | Term DIV Fact     { $$ = $1 / $3; }
    | Fact          { $$ = $1; }
    ;

Fact    : LP Exp RP         { $$ = $2; }
    | NUM           { $$ = $1; }
    ;

%%
int yyerror(char *err)
{
   printf("Error: %s\n", err);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    yyparse();
}
```

I compile and run with the following command
`bison -d calc.y && flex calc.l && gcc -o calculator calc.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl && ./calculator`

This is a sample output (the 5+5 is my input, no result appears):

```
Hello
5+5
```

Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, you specify:

```
%option never-interactive
```

Once you do that, you should not expect to be able to use the program interactively. `never-interactive` is effectively a promise that the program will not be used interactively, and it allows `flex` to generate slightly more efficient code which buffers input instead of reading character by character. As a result, you will not see any output until you either type a lot of expressions or terminate the program by entering an end-of-file marker.

The second problem is that you don't define `YYSTYPE` early enough in `calc.l`:

```
%{
#include "calc.tab.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define YYSTYPE double
%}
```

`yylval` is declared in `calc.tab.h` as `YYSTYPE yylval;`; if `YYSTYPE` is not defined as a macro (when `calc.tab.h` is included), then it is typedef'd to `int`, which has the effect of declaring `yylval` as an `int` in the C file generated by flex. In the C file generated by `bison`, however, `yylval` is declared as a `double`. That's undefined behaviour, and will not be detected by `gcc` because the two translation units are compiled independently and the linker doesn't know anything about types.

The consequence of that error is that the result printed will not be correct. (It is likely to be printed as 0.0, but since it is undefined behaviour, any result is possible.)

So you need to put the `#define` before the `#include`:

```
%{
#define YYSTYPE double
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "calc.tab.h"
%}
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you very much!!
I indeed tried before you replied to supply the input through a file and it would work but thinking all numbers are 0.0 unless I change the whole program to treat them as integers.

Could you tell me though if there's a way to enter end-of-file marker other than `ctrl-d` ?

Comment: @Maverick: the only way to enter an end-of-file marker is ctrl-d. I suggest you remove the `never-interactive` option; the difference in execution time is trivial.